# Can we add integrals on both sides in this equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am reading *The Theoretical Minimum: What You Need to Know to Start Doing Physics* by Leonar Susskind. And while telling *integration by parts* there was a equation like this: (***product rule***) $${d\over dx}[f(x)g(x)] = f'g+g'f$$
Then, Mr. Susskind added integrals to both sides like this: $$\int_a^b{d\over dx}f(x)g(x) = \left[\int_a^bf'g\right]+\left[\int_a^bg'f\right]$$

Can we do something like this, I sure we can (Mr. Susskind does so,) but how can we sure about this? i.e. what is proof of this or a logical explanation?

Comment: If $f(x)=x+1$, then $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^b(x+1)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bx\,\mathrm dx+\int_a^b1\,\mathrm dx$. Why is this true?

Comment: By linearity of Riemann integral

Answer (score 1):

What you can note is that $\int_a^b\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)g(x)]dx$ and $\int_a^b(f^\prime(x)g(x)+f(x)g^\prime(x))dx$ are either both undefined, or both defined and equal. When we write the latter as $\int_a^bf^\prime(x)g(x)dx+\int_a^bf(x)g^\prime(x)dx$, this is valid provided both these integrals are defined, and the quantities they equal [have a defined sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). (In particular, we're not safe if one of these integrals is $\infty$ and the other is $-\infty$.)

Answer (score 0):

Your first equation, $\frac{d}{dx} [fg] = fg' + gf'$ means that the function on the left is equal to the function on the right (at least on some subset of $R$). If those two functions are the same on some interval $(a, b)$, then their integrals on $(a, b)$ must also be equal, since the functions are indistinguishable.

If two mathematical objects, say $x, y$, are the same, wouldn't it follow that an operation (integration in your case) on $a$ would yield the same result as the same operation on $b$? Ex. $x + 2 = y + 2$ (if $x, y$ are numbers)

Comment: To denote the real numbers, please use $\mathbb{R}$, the syntax of which is ```\mathbb{R}```.